# C programming Reading a specific line of a text file

Tags: c, file

So i've been given an exercise to work on: Have the user input a number and the program will display the line of text associated with that line for example

```
Password 
abcdefg 
Star_wars 
jedi
Weapon 
Planet 
long 
nail 
car 
fast 
cover 
machine 
My_little
Alone
Love
Ghast
```

Input 3: Output: Star_wars

Now i have been given a program to solve this, however it uses the function *getline()* , which doesn't complie on DEV C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int end = 1, bytes = 512, loop = 0, line = 0;
char *str = NULL;
FILE *fd = fopen("Student passwords.txt", "r");
if (fd == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to open file\n");
    return -1;
}
    printf("Enter the line number to read : ");
    scanf("%d", &line);

do {
    getline(&str, &bytes, fd);
    loop++;
    if (loop == line)
        end = 0;
}while(end);

printf("\nLine-%d: %s\n", line, str);
    fclose(fd);
}
```

All i need is to know how to do this, in a simple program without the use of getline()

Thanks

Edit: I also don't want to download software to make this work

Comment: First step: properly indent your code; this looks like crap.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/216411/reading-a-file-line-by-line

Comment: about the indentation: that might be WYSIWYG-related.

Comment: doesn't work? i'm not surprised. your passing an `int*` as the `size_t*` buffer length parameter. Do you mean doesn't *compile*? How about a little clarity on the hard-to-be-more-nebulous phrase "doesn't work" ?

Comment: Regarding how to do it, `getline()` (assuming you call it *correctly*) is part of POSIX.1-2008. If your toolchain is more ancient than that you'll likely have to code a solution using something like [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: Did you just replace your **entire question** with a completely different one? The purpose of Q&A sites like StackOverflow is that you can search for questions similar to your problem and (hopefully) find an already answered question. Nobody will be able to make sense of the previous answers without the *original* question. Revert your edit and post a **new question** instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use fgets instead of getline.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int end, loop, line;
    char str[512];
    FILE *fd = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (fd == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Enter the line number to read : ");
    scanf("%d", &line);

    for(end = loop = 0;loop<line;++loop){
        if(0==fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd)){//include '\n'
            end = 1;//can't input (EOF)
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!end)
        printf("\nLine-%d: %s\n", line, str);
    fclose(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have wrote:

```
char *str = NULL;
```

and you used it without initializing:

```
getline(&str, &bytes, fd);
```

first you must initialize it:

```
char *str=(char*)malloc(SIZEOFSTR);
```

Comment: The question is tagged C.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this part in your program instead of your do-while loop. You will be using fscanf() whose arguments are the file pointer, specifier of data type and the variable you want to store.

```
printf("Enter the line number to read : ");
scanf("%d", &line);

while(line--) {
    fscanf(fd,"%s",str);
}

printf("\nLine-%d:%s\n",line,str);
```